# javascript split the element id from window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I am getting the following string from javascript innerHTML using this code.

```
window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
```

output is,

```
<input name="boxes[]" value="checkbox_1" id="box_1" type="checkbox">fgfg
```

How do i get the check box id from the html string.

i need to find out the id value from the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't get the innerHTML, get the element you want instead.

`window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].id`